# Deploying micro services to Pivotal Cloud Foundry and establish communication between the micro services

Tags: microservices, cloud-foundry

I have multiple .Net core micro services where some of the micro services will talk/communicate with the other micro services. I want to deploy these services to Pivotal Cloud Foundry(PCF) each to a different container and need to establish the communication between them.

I have tried using Registry service in PCF which didn't work out.

I wanted to know the steps which are used to establish the communication between the micro services.

Any existing example with code would help out.

Could anybody help on this?

Thanks

Comment: From my though process you might not be using Pivotal dependencies in your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [Steeltoe](https://steeltoe.io/).

Steeltoe client libraries enable .NET Core and .NET Framework apps to easily leverage Netflix Eureka, Hystrix, Spring Cloud Config Server, and Cloud Foundry services.

Comment: They also have samples apps that are very helpful.

Comment: Thanks K.AJ,
Is steeltoe service discovery different from what we have in PCF(Service registry)?

Won't Service registry will work?

Comment: Steeltoe does not create service registry. It enables .net core apps to interact with PCF Service Registry.
You still need PCF Service Registry.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I will try and will come back to you if have any further questions.

Comment: Another project to check out is [DHaven.Faux](https://github.com/bloritsch/DHaven.Faux) which uses the SteelToe framework that is a lot like Netflix Feign (generates the code to call microservices from an interface).  Hystrix support coming soon. (disclaimer: it's my project)